# Angular reactive form get initial value form input field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am using angular 5 and create a reactive form where implement a multiple add input field. This form has a index value that increment form loop ordering. I am using a model to get data. Every data i am getting and working fine but there was some problem, i cant get input field value that auto increment according to loop.
here is my code sample.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="createSurveys(myForm.value)">

<input type="number" class="form-control" [value]="i" formControlName="index" >

</form>


this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)]],
        question_record: this._fb.array([
            this.initQuestions()
        ])
    });

initQuestions() {
    return this._fb.group({
        index: [0]
    });
}
```

result

```
{
 "name": "abcde",
 "data": [
    {
      "title": "sssss",
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "title": "ssss",
       "index": 0,
    }
  ]
}
```

when i console my data all data working find but i cant get index data and it always show default value that i set into the model that is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [formArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group) for looping `this._fb.array([])`

Example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw5zpx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: <input type="number"
           class="form-control text-center"
            id="index"
           formControlName="index" [value]="i">

problem is that want to get index value but always show default value

Comment: See example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw5zpx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: understand but u get data from click index button. my problem is how to get value from input such as want to get value

<input type="text" formControlName=index value="0">
<input type="text" formControlName=index value="1">
<input type="text" formControlName=index value="2">
this value i want to set my model . please give me solution for this problem